# Import Error in Eclipse when importing same name packages

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev

I have a pydev project opened in eclipse.

The project's packages nesting is as follows:

```
my-package:
    my-sub-package:
        foo
```

In this project I am using an import from another project I created.
The other project's nesting is:

```
my-package:
    my-sub-package:
        bar
```

So the 2 main packages have the same names.

When trying to import:
`from my-package.my-sub-package import bar` I get `ImportError: No module named bar`.

I guess that happens because eclipse is searching in the current project and when it doesn't find `bar`, it doesn't look for it in dist-utils (where I pip installed the project I'm trying to import from).

(When trying to do the same import from a regular python opened from the same location, the import works perfectly fine - so it's something in eclipse).

Is there a way to tell eclipse to continue searching for the module in all folders in the pythonpath (so it can reach dist-utils), even when the packages have the same name and it didn't find the right package in the current project?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When in eclipse, check the python path (import sys;sys.path) and check if there is a difference between the result of the equivalent command in the command line (when virtualenv is activated..)

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the regular python from exactly?
If you have

```
src-root:
    my-package:
        __init__.py
        my-sub-package:
            __init__.py
            foo.py
```

and you run the regular python from within src-root then you will get the same result ie that it will not work but if you run it anywhere else it probably will work as you say.

If you can't rename any of the packages the only thing is to remove the current scr-root from the 'Source Folder' in your eclipse PyDev options but not would mean you would never access the foo my-package again.
See http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path